# Use 2D numpy arrays to plot a 3D polyhedron with matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

Suppose I have the following script:

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

N = 100
L1 = 40; L2 = 60; L3 = 20

A1 = np.zeros([N,N])
A2 = np.copy(A1)
A3 = np.copy(A1)

midpoint = int(N/2)
A1[midpoint-int(L1/2):midpoint+int(L1/2), midpoint-int(L1/2):midpoint+int(L1/2)] = 1
A2[midpoint-int(L2/2):midpoint+int(L2/2), midpoint-int(L2/2):midpoint+int(L2/2)] = 1
A3[midpoint-int(L3/2):midpoint+int(L3/2), midpoint-int(L3/2):midpoint+int(L3/2)] = 1
```

How can I plot a polyhedron with A1, A2, and A3 as top, middle, and bottom slices of that polyhedron?

Comment: Look at the answer for this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32707384/plot-a-3d-surface-of-a-polyhedron

Comment: Okay, but that's just a regular cube. How can I draw a more complicated polyhedron such as the one I'm trying to generate? Basically I'm looking for an algorithm-writing strategy here that isn't too complicated.

Comment: A1,A2,A3 are vertices or edges?

Comment: Neither; they are faces.

Comment: Correction; A1, A2, and A3 are slices of the polyhedron.